# Deserialize JSON result

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have developed service which returns JSON data as below

```
{"names":["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"],"validname":false}
```

Now i want to deserialize it in c#.

I have tried with below methods, but still getting error

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(result);
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: You have to create a class

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClass 
{
    public string[] Names { get; set; }
    public bool Validname { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
  var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(result);
```

also you can use JsonProperty attribute to map properties to json like so

```
  [JsonProperty("names")]
  public string[] MyPropertyNamedSomethingDifferent { get; set; }
```

Comment: Then how to convert it?